# Facebook realtime updates certificate verify failed

Tags: facebook, ssl, updates

When I try to test realtime updates, I get following error message:

```
"Callback verification failed: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"
```

Any idea, how to solve this problem?

I tried to test my SSL Certificate (http://www.nsoccer.net) in http://www.digicert.com/help/ and it seems, that there aren't problems.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides an SSL bundle of all required SSL root certificates required with the PHP SDK bundle which you can use to establish a chain of trust. At this time, you can find the bundle at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt. You could use that to modify your application to use these certificates to establish a chain of trust.

Comment: I added following line to httpd-ssl.conf but still having same problem: SSLCACertificateFile "c:/xampp/htdocs/ns/fb/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt"

Comment: @JohannesEski You need to update your code that uses the Facebook API to use that certificate bundle, not Apache.

Comment: Here is settings, how I try to test, but even if I change callback URL to https://www.nsoccer.net/NS/qwerty.php (which doesnt exist), I still get same error: [http://pp.kpnet.fi/kmje/Image16.png](http://pp.kpnet.fi/kmje/Image16.png) Here is anyway callback source [http://pp.kpnet.fi/kmje/callback.txt](http://pp.kpnet.fi/kmje/callback.txt)

Comment: @JohannesEski I misunderstood your problem. Facebook is giving you that error. Then yes you'll need to add some sort of certificate chain bundle that GoDaddy has provided you with. GoDaddy has some instructions at their [support website](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5238/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-apache)